# Reading last message from raw email mime

Tags: python, email

I'm processing raw email mime resulting from users replies, using Python's email module.

The problem is these raw emails include all the messages in the thread but I need to extract only the last message from it.

Also, every email client's mime seems to contain some different representation for the message thread.

Here is a sample mime from Outlook:

```
Return-Path: <pouya795@outlook.com>
Received: from DM4PR02CU002.outbound.protection.outlook.com (mail-centralusazolkn19013006.outbound.protection.outlook.com [52.103.13.6])
 by inbound-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com with SMTP id jfh908ia2r479q97utau7rejhlmdobk5ulkflh01
 for wc64v1ce@email.logimate.io;
 Mon, 18 Dec 2023 14:41:57 +0000 (UTC)
X-SES-Spam-Verdict: PASS
X-SES-Virus-Verdict: PASS
Received-SPF: pass (spfCheck: domain of outlook.com designates 52.103.13.6 as permitted sender) client-ip=52.103.13.6; envelope-from=pouya795@outlook.com; helo=mail-centralusazolkn19013006.outbound.protection.outlook.com;
Authentication-Results: amazonses.com;
 spf=pass (spfCheck: domain of outlook.com designates 52.103.13.6 as permitted sender) client-ip=52.103.13.6; envelope-from=pouya795@outlook.com; helo=mail-centralusazolkn19013006.outbound.protection.outlook.com;
 dkim=pass header.i=@outlook.com;
 dmarc=pass header.from=outlook.com;
X-SES-RECEIPT: AEFBQUFBQUFBQUFIOGVYQVZ4a3hXNnlFWG5wMnI1Y2RpWXVBOFRzcnBEZjBmQm5aUUdtQkVYY3dxeWphTDV2WjZ4dC9XcUdNd29mZGJBWlFVcEExSXhPMUR1R1A0ZGpsSlI4eFZMVWlISGVWSFZFUnZoWmZHdEFmY0RDclR3V0YxMEQ2YVpJVEVlMEtCRVRrc3VmZXk2ZmRXVVVVNjB0WHZvMUtPNzhvcjBrZkt6ZHJBSk52bnJnN0J5akFOT2lpeUY2dzZqKzJBTndlS3BqUy84NHp3MHhzY0I2TTVTUFZJNEI1cEJ0YU1Tb0wzazJsK09TSzQwaktqb09CcE1qRnlUVTdvbWNISnVkaWhJNWhWM2prM09ldndzTDJCTllIUEduOGhLWk5DNDBzNlRFdk44dk5xd3c9PQ==
X-SES-DKIM-SIGNATURE: a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; b=B9WA39epTaS3Ltfa3Sqt0u4Wj8095VM5n1TW1JLPSPEVSjp2FmQ/uF/ITkkwhZ2cIPzFN4B2bM2bmhNODLPQYYwOiSIzU2e1c8184WSNUw2cquppygElCSxIw8QRneOiyNLnypFLEQrchdhTDX3Atn7x1IV6EFHwAEIWqKqNVig=; c=relaxed/simple; s=224i4yxa5dv7c2xz3womw6peuasteono; d=amazonses.com; t=1702910517; v=1; bh=XDoiuxTmgerst0MLnEFXbQieRxXcO+LgclIq5dPrr+0=; h=From:To:Cc:Bcc:Subject:Date:Message-ID:MIME-Version:Content-Type:X-SES-RECEIPT;
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; s=arcselector9901; d=microsoft.com; cv=none;
 b=TpTBEC0RbRBBbfSHR9HLSfJSgUwUsYEg3KqwpbECJc19MHrLQGhJqkWJtvPPY7LIBr1pVZf+kKvqeTUJAaDAxlGvRTG7Ll8mqHWfafg60io0qyAtALKSpd81phEeuxPYkRC6k9pqt4ggQb6OIURhGssu4ybJW43Sp9bripmzckh2RRzBbrAcqU8IQTCzsTh6ajJN6ohdHqXPtx8KRHAh/tafqdbhUkutqHAHqxnaEA1yAyyXqna//Hi/7w7t7bohy90acKqdDi8KuzP4eco0h5IQaPkAHLEtqnpW3GtTiOlCua8cT5UM0phnv94aEFZfv44kFPk5i+kZvgQrHnqf/w==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=microsoft.com;
 s=arcselector9901;
 h=From:Date:Subject:Message-ID:Content-Type:MIME-Version:X-MS-Exchange-AntiSpam-MessageData-ChunkCount:X-MS-Exchange-AntiSpam-MessageData-0:X-MS-Exchange-AntiSpam-MessageData-1;
 bh=Bl8r8gD3YbICeOcA1fNV76mctiP6lQVo4yvuVJ/OaJ8=;
 b=gGNzpvThArgZXJfgoh3/IM6HBp+z64prkl9vxNIXJlLpns8WoNP6CDl44C2uH1bcICFYB9gZLCvjsUIzhjrUc5UKeXpmxkR/WRPIA9mPYq74/BgvsIlYX3Bfft+lMi1HkzHJp9NlbnCKIe4j9J3P3hHYVyj2zTWlN8JIstUgkxhDk8j1JsEpBTiUm/AXQjGC95ZC9+i4MWFxx+XVOYMB+7OSMh/p3ulIjG4WS9LFvRKjJsXipO2pCQ6q9EnOLxWZqkTHFDFPygP3IWF2sX/64D8g5WracuO/s7scYh803p71Omv7ZjqMRYeeYSraGJGsG6o34rLK9wQvzjCYorGaOw==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.microsoft.com 1; spf=none; dmarc=none;
 dkim=none; arc=none
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=outlook.com;
 s=selector1;
 h=From:Date:Subject:Message-ID:Content-Type:MIME-Version:X-MS-Exchange-SenderADCheck;
 bh=Bl8r8gD3YbICeOcA1fNV76mctiP6lQVo4yvuVJ/OaJ8=;
 b=QMOylYpMFrvWp+nxABkOSQWy10nUFQymWYCF3zOOQBuCTWLiV7XlZiggfR2GFk3JS0dPPidTwOLaL3yL+alUZ1iVFs1a7NtmzoMAJ5p1rIQKZdveEeW4mdQxv/lmKzk646FFf6Q/Sem0dzut4tabEnQzRR4U+TUm/pr0v5+2mnkvgdfUwyBcYQxA4EhaKOHXTRsnWLbZc8E/2Tz+GNfSSLpYnEI4m+y6R1P+m0+hwVHNcisJdPPJD+OhS/qKjGw5CKvi83EqCelgCWW1gzvofowRzifaXMTIbSYfVDP2fq39yaNv5mQlDzCm+uJz0iL4P4vtkLJ4oOwggkKGwVDDmQ==
Received: from BYAPR05MB5829.namprd05.prod.outlook.com (2603:10b6:a03:d0::28)
 by BLAPR05MB7441.namprd05.prod.outlook.com (2603:10b6:208:296::12) with
 Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.7091.37; Mon, 18 Dec
 2023 14:41:55 +0000
Received: from BYAPR05MB5829.namprd05.prod.outlook.com
 ([fe80::d5ea:c86c:ed32:3c06]) by BYAPR05MB5829.namprd05.prod.outlook.com
 ([fe80::d5ea:c86c:ed32:3c06%7]) with mapi id 15.20.7091.034; Mon, 18 Dec 2023
 14:41:55 +0000
From: Pouya Kermanshahi <pouya795@outlook.com>
To: "wc64v1ce@email.logimate.io" <wc64v1ce@email.logimate.io>
Subject: Re: eefe (ID:wc64v1ce)
Thread-Topic: eefe (ID:wc64v1ce)
Thread-Index: AQHaMZk2z1q5k5vJ6Eq/HTm6AsPAL7Cuz/X+gAAAekWAAAA1Z4AATGPlgAAAadQ=
Date: Mon, 18 Dec 2023 14:41:55 +0000
Message-ID:
 <BYAPR05MB582960E4A24B95E13EC5C6829590A@BYAPR05MB5829.namprd05.prod.outlook.com>
References:
 <0100018c7c5fd117-fd33a739-3997-476a-8038-a888c594f6fb-000000@email.amazonses.com>
 <BYAPR05MB582910A69F1F869E7071EB3F9590A@BYAPR05MB5829.namprd05.prod.outlook.com>
 <BYAPR05MB582949C1EF549BD34AE1E6DA9590A@BYAPR05MB5829.namprd05.prod.outlook.com>
 <BYAPR05MB5829047E2D05EE87F069AD249590A@BYAPR05MB5829.namprd05.prod.outlook.com>
 <BYAPR05MB58292EAA0CBC32EEB836C58B9590A@BYAPR05MB5829.namprd05.prod.outlook.com>
In-Reply-To:
 <BYAPR05MB58292EAA0CBC32EEB836C58B9590A@BYAPR05MB5829.namprd05.prod.outlook.com>
Accept-Language: en-US
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach:
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
msip_labels:
x-tmn: [VJ33kUR7M5quzl/PQeV+H5q24CWLZo5p]
x-ms-publictraffictype: Email
x-ms-traffictypediagnostic: BYAPR05MB5829:EE_|BLAPR05MB7441:EE_
x-ms-office365-filtering-correlation-id: 433a6d7a-095a-49b6-bf55-08dbffd77b42
x-microsoft-antispam: BCL:0;
x-microsoft-antispam-message-info:
 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
x-ms-exchange-antispam-messagedata-chunkcount: 1
x-ms-exchange-antispam-messagedata-0:
 =?us-ascii?Q?NbJxLfrIMKpXEb0zOjnxtpzr277NljFP1HCsBmAXVkG77gkCI7B2o4TwTBXz?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?LZhdbhCpl1PObeE8OvTmNtiEe1ki4PK65QYQJgVCam/0c9sl//X3k3IevPWl?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?D/UUvfzRwrZ8WaTMQvZr4X2dkHpNDDdZAMfVUVZBw5gEGNsS6eVObRdoOL2T?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?2VcQ9UIT1/7rIw6dydkkSXK9gbAfVZrvaUy7XM72Nw1MmzYvl3vT0W1cPw+t?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?6WNvU5xepqR7v5cf+9ZvLypFV9TvrBofc3hd0Et7O/ozuARcy3g1abIMAUQi?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?tNnWPZD0n3Iy5cQkNsPZnmAcfP4XnAw6C/nOABAbUhQ1anVpKV7w/npmpLJu?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?fhtmsbXGnJd0y84Hg7mm8CeXxP6wccYLOHoQG3x0t6gYV0dC7I4E+IvqTZtP?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?yTCiERceUZh7GISVJGtX91VgP5y6czZhw2JvQ5IFqag53UzHIrPSzl9o9Cqc?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?xk0VDd7eyY1mYVHP7O9X7IFm4pIjffHFESAjb1eLCWQPtzFw7vcDIZ1IE+bH?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?tUSfB4HjKbMZKTBKVxWHwUrf0L7Dx/Um81NxnShWHInCnsR2JIKweTLnABeu?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?3U+xNnDpmqwMrJIB3np/UouOTRsUUd5LSPNWn8yO04PEVBPCSMSDxCdq9Gy4?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?D3ysqNIwpBD+OAu3rcE5megFU0Wdk2lddFZpBPHWfD6vo/GeW923G3BIm8C+?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?GNqdPmKrJ9H7qEk/a0QpbzhZbssqzshW5zt6+CWt4xlqzuFzzlJPEWlDgGlE?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?rdqQhdyzi7d0iCvWuIN9YpNa9D7Se6KTFHqYn3dAdpahbp4dVpe/MLMJqF93?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?1fv94ABMsWf7HSUybmiNJm56LVpCLhFl+IbKwLNAH86nt9lWEWeUZgnS7pDx?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?Ekl87a7X7aaaQE6vBC79NUGTYrje/DxhLGP61IeduWo75JtenkggnunY+AzS?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?56Kt39gRifOeMUuF2viDTeXOghGZ+3SV85YpTMdaq5qMQZZTw5EOLnVaQML4?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?x5/RYm0lR8QVG2+0mS59atfttbPZA/re57Fm9zfHmqDgUMisQzyyHfyKTWOX?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?NFIjKCDGhfaS/4gJUGZNDiPQsRziU+kvckO09Zak7Rw/2wyNYqQCnsd0G4as?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?GQ4Gxv6f7MgREY4FRosONwerwhmYqKZnuxE0+Aeg9Qgk6e2Bw5pU/fbdf+Uc?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?LnFDqGRQnjRpFS3W5qOBpSKe7GTWbY8C7+V02g=3D=3D?=
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="_000_BYAPR05MB582960E4A24B95E13EC5C6829590ABYAPR05MB5829namp_"
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-OriginatorOrg: outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-AuthAs: Internal
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-AuthSource: BYAPR05MB5829.namprd05.prod.outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-RMS-PersistedConsumerOrg: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Network-Message-Id: 433a6d7a-095a-49b6-bf55-08dbffd77b42
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-originalarrivaltime: 18 Dec 2023 14:41:55.3809
 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-fromentityheader: Hosted
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-id: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-rms-persistedconsumerorg: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: BLAPR05MB7441

--_000_BYAPR05MB582960E4A24B95E13EC5C6829590ABYAPR05MB5829namp_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

bol number: 1234678
________________________________
From: Pouya Kermanshahi <pouya795@outlook.com>
Sent: Monday, December 18, 2023 6:11 PM
To: wc64v1ce@email.logimate.io <wc64v1ce@email.logimate.io>
Subject: Re: eefe (ID:wc64v1ce)

bol number: 12346

________________________________
From: Pouya Kermanshahi <pouya795@outlook.com>
Sent: Monday, December 18, 2023 1:37 PM
To: wc64v1ce@email.logimate.io <wc64v1ce@email.logimate.io>
Subject: Re: eefe (ID:wc64v1ce)

bol number: 1234
________________________________
From: Pouya Kermanshahi <pouya795@outlook.com>
Sent: Monday, December 18, 2023 1:36 PM
To: wc64v1ce@email.logimate.io <wc64v1ce@email.logimate.io>
Subject: Re: eefe (ID:wc64v1ce)

bol number 123456
________________________________
From: Pouya Kermanshahi <pouya795@outlook.com>
Sent: Monday, December 18, 2023 1:35 PM
To: wc64v1ce@email.logimate.io <wc64v1ce@email.logimate.io>
Subject: Re: eefe (ID:wc64v1ce)

shipper phone: +989212617107
consignee phone: +9893626541
bol number: 1234
________________________________
From: wc64v1ce@email.logimate.io <wc64v1ce@email.logimate.io>
Sent: Monday, December 18, 2023 1:31 PM
To: pouya795@outlook.com <pouya795@outlook.com>
Cc: pouya795@gmail.com <pouya795@gmail.com>
Subject: eefe (ID:wc64v1ce)

eefe (ID:wc64v1ce)
Hi Pouya

grgrg

Cargo Details:

Product Description:

Lac; gums, resins and other vegetable saps and extracts

Hs Code: 13

Delivery Details:

Shipment Type: Sea

containers: LCL

From: The Palm Jumeirah

To: Umm Al Nar

Ready to Load: Dec. 18, 2023

- Pouya Kermanshahi

create a quote <https://panel.logimate.io/forwarder/test/wc64v1ce/quote> ht=
tps://panel.logimate.io/forwarder/test/wc64v1ce/quote
<https://logimate.io>
[https://d1oxptougqju7t.cloudfront.net/logimate-logo-new.png]   Sent By Log=
imate

--_000_BYAPR05MB582960E4A24B95E13EC5C6829590ABYAPR05MB5829namp_
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dus-ascii"=
>
<style type=3D"text/css" style=3D"display:none;"> P {margin-top:0;margin-bo=
ttom:0;} </style>
</head>
<body dir=3D"ltr">
<div class=3D"elementToProof"><span style=3D"letter-spacing: normal; font-f=
amily: Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; c=
olor: black; background-color: white;">bol number: 1234</span><span style=
=3D"letter-spacing: normal; font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif; fo=
nt-size: 12pt; font-weight: 400; color: black; background-color: rgb(255, 2=
55, 255);">6</span><span style=3D"font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, sans-ser=
if; font-size: 12pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">78</span></div>
<div id=3D"appendonsend"></div>
<hr style=3D"display:inline-block;width:98%" tabindex=3D"-1">
<div id=3D"divRplyFwdMsg" dir=3D"ltr"><font face=3D"Calibri, sans-serif" st=
yle=3D"font-size:11pt" color=3D"#000000"><b>From:</b> Pouya Kermanshahi &lt=
;pouya795@outlook.com&gt;<br>
<b>Sent:</b> Monday, December 18, 2023 6:11 PM<br>
<b>To:</b> wc64v1ce@email.logimate.io &lt;wc64v1ce@email.logimate.io&gt;<br=
>
<b>Subject:</b> Re: eefe (ID:wc64v1ce)</font>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<style type=3D"text/css" style=3D"display:none">
<!--
p
    {margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:0}
-->
</style>
<div dir=3D"ltr">
<div class=3D"x_elementToProof"><span style=3D"letter-spacing:normal; font-=
family:Calibri,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:16px; font-weight:400; color=
:rgb(0,0,0); background-color:rgb(255,255,255)">bol number: 1234</span><spa=
n style=3D"font-family:Calibri,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:12pt; color:=
rgb(0,0,0)">6</span></div>
<div class=3D"x_elementToProof"><span style=3D"font-family:Calibri,Helvetic=
a,sans-serif; font-size:12pt; color:rgb(0,0,0)"><br>
</span></div>
<div id=3D"x_appendonsend"></div>
<hr tabindex=3D"-1" style=3D"display:inline-block; width:98%">
<div id=3D"x_divRplyFwdMsg" dir=3D"ltr"><font face=3D"Calibri, sans-serif" =
color=3D"#000000" style=3D"font-size:11pt"><b>From:</b> Pouya Kermanshahi &=
lt;pouya795@outlook.com&gt;<br>
<b>Sent:</b> Monday, December 18, 2023 1:37 PM<br>
<b>To:</b> wc64v1ce@email.logimate.io &lt;wc64v1ce@email.logimate.io&gt;<br=
>
<b>Subject:</b> Re: eefe (ID:wc64v1ce)</font>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<style type=3D"text/css" style=3D"display:none">
<!--
p
    {margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:0}
-->
</style>
<div dir=3D"ltr">
<div class=3D"x_x_elementToProof" style=3D"font-family:Calibri,Helvetica,sa=
ns-serif; font-size:12pt; color:rgb(0,0,0)">
bol number: 1234</div>
<div id=3D"x_x_appendonsend"></div>
<hr tabindex=3D"-1" style=3D"display:inline-block; width:98%">
<div id=3D"x_x_divRplyFwdMsg" dir=3D"ltr"><font face=3D"Calibri, sans-serif=
" color=3D"#000000" style=3D"font-size:11pt"><b>From:</b> Pouya Kermanshahi=
 &lt;pouya795@outlook.com&gt;<br>
<b>Sent:</b> Monday, December 18, 2023 1:36 PM<br>
<b>To:</b> wc64v1ce@email.logimate.io &lt;wc64v1ce@email.logimate.io&gt;<br=
>
<b>Subject:</b> Re: eefe (ID:wc64v1ce)</font>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<style type=3D"text/css" style=3D"display:none">
<!--
p
    {margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:0}
-->
</style>
<div dir=3D"ltr">
<div class=3D"x_x_x_elementToProof" style=3D"font-family:Calibri,Helvetica,=
sans-serif; font-size:12pt; color:rgb(0,0,0)">
bol number 123456</div>
<div id=3D"x_x_x_appendonsend"></div>
<hr tabindex=3D"-1" style=3D"display:inline-block; width:98%">
<div id=3D"x_x_x_divRplyFwdMsg" dir=3D"ltr"><font face=3D"Calibri, sans-ser=
if" color=3D"#000000" style=3D"font-size:11pt"><b>From:</b> Pouya Kermansha=
hi &lt;pouya795@outlook.com&gt;<br>
<b>Sent:</b> Monday, December 18, 2023 1:35 PM<br>
<b>To:</b> wc64v1ce@email.logimate.io &lt;wc64v1ce@email.logimate.io&gt;<br=
>
<b>Subject:</b> Re: eefe (ID:wc64v1ce)</font>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<style type=3D"text/css" style=3D"display:none">
<!--
p
    {margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:0}
-->
</style>
<div dir=3D"ltr">
<div class=3D"x_x_x_x_elementToProof" style=3D"font-family:Calibri,Helvetic=
a,sans-serif; font-size:12pt; color:rgb(0,0,0)">
shipper phone: +989212617107</div>
<div class=3D"x_x_x_x_elementToProof" style=3D"font-family:Calibri,Helvetic=
a,sans-serif; font-size:12pt; color:rgb(0,0,0)">
consignee phone: +9893626541</div>
<div class=3D"x_x_x_x_elementToProof" style=3D"font-family:Calibri,Helvetic=
a,sans-serif; font-size:12pt; color:rgb(0,0,0)">
bol number: 1234</div>
<div id=3D"x_x_x_x_appendonsend"></div>
<hr tabindex=3D"-1" style=3D"display:inline-block; width:98%">
<div id=3D"x_x_x_x_divRplyFwdMsg" dir=3D"ltr"><font face=3D"Calibri, sans-s=
erif" color=3D"#000000" style=3D"font-size:11pt"><b>From:</b> wc64v1ce@emai=
l.logimate.io &lt;wc64v1ce@email.logimate.io&gt;<br>
<b>Sent:</b> Monday, December 18, 2023 1:31 PM<br>
<b>To:</b> pouya795@outlook.com &lt;pouya795@outlook.com&gt;<br>
<b>Cc:</b> pouya795@gmail.com &lt;pouya795@gmail.com&gt;<br>
<b>Subject:</b> eefe (ID:wc64v1ce)</font>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<style>
<!--
table, a, p, span, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
    {font-family:'Inter',sans-serif}
a
    {text-decoration:none}
p
    {margin-bottom:0}
#x_x_x_x_x_main-table
    {width:100%;
    padding:30px 5px 0}
#x_x_x_x_x_content-table
    {padding-right:10px;
    padding-left:10px}
#x_x_x_x_x_main-title
    {font-weight:bold;
    font-size:20px}
#x_x_x_x_x_footer-container
    {margin-top:10px}
-->
</style>
<div style=3D"font-family:'Inter'; font-size:16px; display:flex; flex-direc=
tion:column">
<table id=3D"x_x_x_x_x_main-table" style=3D"background-color:#1D1F2B; borde=
r-radius:12px; border-spacing:10px">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style=3D"padding-bottom:20px">
<h1 id=3D"x_x_x_x_x_main-title" style=3D"font-style:normal; margin:0 auto; =
text-align:center; letter-spacing:-0.01em; color:#FFFFFF">
eefe (ID:wc64v1ce) </h1>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table id=3D"x_x_x_x_x_content-table" style=3D"border-spacing:20px; text-al=
ign:left!important; background:#FFFFFF; box-shadow:0px 10px 50px rgba(45,48=
,68,0.25); border-radius:12px; width:100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<h3 style=3D"font-weight:600; font-size:16px; line-height:19px; color:#2D30=
44; margin-bottom:0">
Hi Pouya </h3>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<p style=3D"margin:0"></p>
<p>grgrg</p>
<p></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div style=3D"margin-bottom:40px">
<p style=3D"font-weight:bold">Cargo Details:</p>
<p style=3D"word-break:break-word">Product Description: </p>
<p style=3D"text-align:left">Lac; gums, resins and other vegetable saps and=
 extracts
</p>
<p>Hs Code: 13</p>
</div>
<div>
<p style=3D"font-weight:bold">Delivery Details:</p>
<p>Shipment Type: Sea </p>
<div style=3D"margin:0">
<p>containers: LCL </p>
</div>
<div>
<p>From: The Palm Jumeirah</p>
</div>
<div>
<p>To: Umm Al Nar</p>
</div>
<p>Ready to Load: Dec. 18, 2023</p>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span>
<p style=3D"font-style:italic">- Pouya Kermanshahi </p>
</span></td>
</tr>
<tr style=3D"margin-top:30px">
<td style=3D"text-align:center; margin-top:30px"><a href=3D"https://panel.l=
ogimate.io/forwarder/test/wc64v1ce/quote" target=3D"_blank" style=3D"margin=
-right:auto; margin-left:auto; text-decoration:none; background:#303FC7; bo=
rder-radius:12px; font-style:normal; font-weight:600; font-size:13px; line-=
height:16px; width:fit-content; margin-bottom:21px; text-align:center; colo=
r:#FFFFFF; padding:12px 30px; display:block">create
 a quote </a><a href=3D"https://panel.logimate.io/forwarder/test/wc64v1ce/q=
uote" style=3D"width:fit-content; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto; disp=
lay:block">https://panel.logimate.io/forwarder/test/wc64v1ce/quote
</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table id=3D"x_x_x_x_x_footer-container" style=3D"color:#FFFFFF; text-align=
:center; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><a href=3D"https://logimate.io">
<table style=3D"color:#FFFFFF; display:flex">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><img style=3D"width:30px; margin-top:4px; margin-right:10px" src=3D"htt=
ps://d1oxptougqju7t.cloudfront.net/logimate-logo-new.png">
</td>
<td>Sent By Logimate </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

--_000_BYAPR05MB582960E4A24B95E13EC5C6829590ABYAPR05MB5829namp_--
```